# how should C# linq orderby thenby be used?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects modeling toolbars and I'm trying to sort it based on 4 properties:

```
List<MenuItemViewModel> sortingList = new List<MenuItemViewModel>;
FillSortingList();
sortingList.OrderBy(m => m.RoleId)
            .ThenBy(m => m.ToolbarLocation)
            .ThenBy(m => m.Band)
            .ThenBy(m => m.BandIndex);
```

The objects are of type:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel : ViewModel
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCheckable { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int RoleId { get; private set; }
    public int Band  { get;  set; }
    public int BandIndex { get;  set; }
    public ToolbarLocation { get;  set; }
}
```

ToolbarLocation is enum of same name:

```
public enum ToolbarLocation
{
    Left = 0,
    Top = 1,
    Float = 2
}
```

The sorted list is ok regarding RoleId, but within range of one RoleId the locations Top and Left are mixed. Same with Band values 0 and 1. The only order within range of one role is by the BandIndex.

So to me it seems it's doing:

```
_sortingList.OrderBy(m => m.RoleId).ThenBy(m => m.BandIndex);
```

Comment: You have not shown us what Band Or BandIndex are, so it is hard to really help

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: i edited, they are integers

Comment: Are you sure your problem isn't that you're expecting the sorting to happen *in-place*? Call `.ToList()` on the end and reassign `_sortingList` if so.

Comment: Can you show the created list?

Comment: @Ani : That's exactly what i'm expecting. The code was complete even though down voters thought there is something missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has no ordering.

What it has is code to generate a new query to order a list - but that is never executed.

```
sortingList.OrderBy(m => m.RoleId)
             .ThenBy(m => m.ToolbarLocation)
             .ThenBy(m => m.Band)
             .ThenBy(m => m.BandIndex);
```

The return of these calls is an `IQueryable` that has to be executed. You never do `.OrderBy` etc. do NOT change the input data.

A foreach, ToList etc. materializes the new result set.

Comment: thanks. that was the problem indeed.